How to interpret and adjust the colorbar when plotting an RGB image with imshow?
I have a 2x2x3 numpy array like this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

red = np.array([[0, 50], [100, 200]])
green = np.array([[0, 185], [100, 255]])
blue = np.array([[0, 129], [0, 255]])

combined = np.stack((red, green, blue), -1)
# [[[  0,   0,   0],
#   [ 50, 185, 129]],
#  [[100, 100,   0],
#   [200, 255, 255]]]

I can plot the array with color just fine.
plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(
  X=combined,
  vmin=0, 
  vmax=255, 
  interpolation='none',
  aspect='equal',
)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()


I can also plot just the red channel, like this
reds = combined.copy()
reds[:, :, 1:] = 0

plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(
  X=reds,
  vmin=0, 
  vmax=255, 
  interpolation='none',
  aspect='equal',
)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()


But I'm struggling with two questions..

Is the colorbar in the first plot event valid. I'm not sure how to interpret it.
How do change the colorbar in the second plot to go from 0 (black) to 255 (red), as it should? Obviously I want the colorbar values and scale to match the actual plot behavior.


Colors are 3D, colorbar is 1D, do you see a problem here?

The colorbar function accepts a mappable that can be used to specify the colors.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html

I figured the first plot's colorbar was invalid, but I was surprised matplotlib didn't tell me.

You can use LinearSegmentedColormap() and pass it to cmap:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


def get_colorbar(X):
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('black_and_red', ((0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)))
    plt.figure()
    im = plt.imshow(
        X=X,
        cmap=cmap,
        vmin=0,
        vmax=255,
        interpolation='none',
        aspect='equal',
    )
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()


red = np.array([[0, 50], [100, 200]])
green = np.array([[0, 185], [100, 255]])
blue = np.array([[0, 129], [0, 255]])
combined = np.stack((red, green, blue), -1)
get_colorbar(combined[:, :, 0])




Comments

The colorbar in the first plot is also invalid.

how can the colorbar on the first plot be valid? The colours on that plot are RGB colours, but the colorbar is a based on a mapping to the viridis colormap. What do the values on the colorbar represent, and how do they correspond to the colours on the plot? (Hint: they don't). – tmdavison



how can the colorbar on the first plot be valid? The colours on that plot are RGB colours, but the colorbar is a based on a mapping to the viridis colormap. What do the values on the colorbar represent, and how do they correspond to the colours on the plot? (Hint: they don't).
